# Construct extension of function

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

If $u \in W^{3,p}(\mathbb{R}^{+})$ how can we construct the catoptric extension $\overline{u}$ of $u$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (reflection) such that $\overline{u} \in W^{3,p}(\mathbb{R})$ ?

**EDIT**: By setting $v(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix} u''(x) &, x>0 \\  u''(-x) &, x<0  \end{matrix}\right.$ we get:

$$w(x)=u'(0)+\int_0^x v(t) dt=\left\{\begin{matrix} u'(x) &, x>0 \\  2u'(0)-u'(-x) &, x<0  \end{matrix}\right.$$

How do we use this in order to get an $\overline{u}$ such that $\overline{u}=u$ in $(0,\infty)$ where $\overline{u} \in W^{3,p}(\mathbb{R})$?

**EDIT 2**: If we would want the extension to be in $W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R})$ we could pick the following:

$$\overline{u}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
u(x) &, x \geq 0 \\ 
-3u(-x)+4{u\left(-\frac{x}{2} \right )} & , x \leq 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

How can we get an extension that is in $W^{3,p}(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas to get you started:

If you were using the space $W^{1,p}(\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R} \R^+)$ you would define the reflection $\bar u(x) = u(-x)$ for $x < 0$ and $\bar u(x) = u(x)$ for $x > 0$. This gives you continuity of $\bar u$ at $x = 0$ from which the absolute continuity of $\bar u$ follows.

Suppose instead you are using the space $W^{2,p}(\R^+)$. In this case both $u$ and its derivative $u'$ are absolutely continuous. If you use the same definition of $\bar u$ you run into the problem that $\bar u'(x) = - u'(-x)$ for negative $x$  and $\bar u'(x) = u'(x)$ for $x > 0$ so that $\bar u'$ can fail to be continuous at the origin. One way around this is to define the derivative of $\bar u$ first using reflection: define
$$v(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} u'(x) & x > 0 \\ u'(-x) & x < 0 \end{array} \right.$$ so that $v$ is absolutely continuous and then define $$\bar u(x) = u(0) + \int_0^x v(t) \, dt.$$ This is almost the right extension--you can check that it satisfies $$\bar u(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} u(x) & x > 0 \\ 2u(0) - u(-x) & x < 0 \end{array} \right.$$
but it has the problem that $\bar u$ may fail to be integrable on the whole line. You can fix this if you multiply $\bar u$ by a suitable cut-off function that equals zero for negative numbers sufficiently far from the origin, and that equals $1$ for all positive numbers.

What about $W^{3,p}(\R^+)$? Start by reflecting the second derivative.

Comment: First of all, when $u \in W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^{+})$, doesn't it  have to hold that $u, u', u'' \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^{+})$ ? Secondly, why do we want the extension to be integrable? @UmbertoP.

Comment: "Integrable" is shorthand for belonging to the correct $L^p$ space. In the example above $\bar u'$ belongs to $L^p(\mathbb R)$ but $\bar u$ does not, so it must be modified away from the origin.

Comment: Considering $\overline{u}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
u(x) & , x>0\\ 
2u(0)-u(-x) &, x<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$ we have $\overline{u}''(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
u''(x) & , x>0\\ 
-u''(-x) &, x<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$, so $u \notin W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R})$ , it just holds that $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R})$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: The highest order derivative doesn't have to be continuous.

Comment: So do we do it as follows? @UmbertoP. $$$$
We set $v(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
u''(x) &, x>0 \\ 
u''(-x) &, x<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$
$$$$
Then $\overline{u}(x)=u'(0)+\int_0^x v(t) dt=\left\{\begin{matrix}
u'(x) &, x>0 \\ 
2u'(0)-u'(-x) &, x<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Comment: Take one more definite integral to get $\bar u = u$ on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: What do you mean? What can we do in order to get $\overline{u}=u$ in $(0, \infty)$ ? @UmbertoP.

Comment: You mean that we set $w(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
w'(x) &,x>0 \\ 
-w'(-x) &,x<0 
\end{matrix}\right.$ ? How do we use this?

Comment: Could you maybe explain to me how we can find an extension $\overline{u}$ of $u$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\overline{u} \in W^{3,p}(\mathbb{R})$ ? Do we use both $v$ and $w$ ? If so, how? @UmbertoP.

Comment: If we would want the extension to be in $W^{2,p}(\mathbb{R})$ we could pick the following:

$$\overline{u}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
u(x) &, x \geq 0 \\ 
-3u(-x)+4{u\left(-\frac{x}{2} \right )} & , x \leq 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

How can we get an extension that is in $W^{3,p}(\mathbb{R})$ ?